# col-md class affecting col-xs viewport

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

need some clarification with regards to bootstrap classes. I have applied margin-top of 20px to col-md-5, everything works fine if the viewport size is greater than 990px, when the viewport is less than that col-md-5 gets applied to it. I thought col-md-5 would apply only if the viewport is greater than 990px, am i wrong. if yes then what would be the right way to fix this.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-2 col-md-2">
            <div class="icon">
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="col-xs-10 col-md-5">Lorem Ipsum</div>
          <div class="col-xs-10 col-md-5">Lorem Ipsum</div>
     </div>
</div>


.row{
  border : 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius : 5px;
  padding : 5px;
  text-align : center;
}

.icon{
  width:50px;
  height : 50px;
  background-color : #eee;
  border-radius : 50%;
}

.col-md-5{
  margin-top : 18px;
}
```

Comment: Please enter your code here on SO, not just link to it, which can change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`col-md-*` will always be "applied". I think you're confused about the @media queries that change *how* the classes are applied at specific breakpoints.

If you want to only apply CSS at greater than 990 use a @media query..

```
@media screen and (min-width: 990px) {
  .col-md-5 {
    margin-top: 18px;
  }
}
```

Demo: http://bootply.com/Wu4p0tM6g7

Comment: Thank you for clarification. I was indeed confused with media queries. I thought col-md-* classes would only get applied if the viewport is greater than 990px.